# AWK removal of lines in CSV with two(or more) empty fields?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the following file, called `new2.csv`:

```
101583815|1605227222|1605227234|412_99_0122818689|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|10000|0|0|10000|MARIA
101583815||2005227222|412_99_0122818689|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|10000|0|0|10000
101583815|   ||420_99_0122818689|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|10000|0|0|10000
101583815|   |4905227222|420_99_0122818689|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|10000|0|0|10000
101578445|HOLA|1605434338|412_99_0123259149|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|8000|0|0|8000
101583816||1805434338|420_99_0122818689|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|10000|0|0|10000
```

I would like to only retain rows that have values in the 2nd or 3rd column. I tried with:

```
awk -F "|" '(NR>1) && (($2$3)~/[^[:space:]]/)' new2.csv
```

but this prints line 2.

Desired output: (

```
101583815|1605227222|1605227234|412_99_0122818689|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|10000|0|0|10000|MARIA
101578445|HOLA|1605434338|412_99_0123259149|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|8000|0|0|8000
```

Comment: I tried to clarify, I am not quite sure what the `output.nook` is (output that is not OK?), and you seem to be explicitly skipping the first line in your `awk` command but don't mention that. Does your file have a header we are supposed to skip?

Comment: Also, you say you want lines with values in the 2nd _or_ 3rd column, but your desired output is only lines that have values in the 2nd _and_ 3rd column. Which do you actually want?

Comment: yes, but the important is filter the empty fields and the fields with an space ... works for the space but not for the empty -> ""

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the actual file, including the header. Also clarify if you want lines that have a 2nd AND 3rd field, or lines that have either a second OR a third OR both.

Comment: EDITED .. sorry my english

Comment: Don't worry, we don't expect people here to speak perfect English! I know how hard it is to try and explain something in a foreign language. But you say OR and yet you show the desired output as AND (line 4 has no 2nd field, but it has a 3rd field and yet you don't have it in your desired output), so I think you want both 2 and 3 to be not empty.

Comment: The `NR>1` in your script will stop it from printing the first line of your sample input. Did you forget to include a header line in your example? If so, please [edit] your example to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

With the example file you have given, and based on the desired output, assuming that fields are defined by `|`, you want is to print those lines whose 2nd and 3rd field are not empty or just whitespace. If so, you need:

```
$ awk -F "|" '$2~/[^[:space:]]/ && $3~/[^[:space:]]/' new2.csv
101583815|1605227222|1605227234|412_99_0122818689|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|10000|0|0|10000|MARIA
101578445|HOLA|1605434338|412_99_0123259149|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|8000|0|0|8000
```

If you also want to skip a header, use:

```
awk -F "|" 'NR>1 && $2~/[^[:space:]]/ && $3~/[^[:space:]]/' new2.csv
```

And if you actually want lines where *either* the 2nd *or* the 3rd, *or* both are non-empty, use:

```
awk -F "|" 'NR>1 && ($2~/[^[:space:]]/ || $3~/[^[:space:]]/)' new2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the output you say you want (`retain rows that have values in the 2nd or 3rd column`):

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*' '($2$3) != ""' file
101583815|1605227222|1605227234|412_99_0122818689|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|10000|0|0|10000|MARIA
101583815||2005227222|412_99_0122818689|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|10000|0|0|10000
101583815|   |4905227222|420_99_0122818689|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|10000|0|0|10000
101578445|HOLA|1605434338|412_99_0123259149|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|8000|0|0|8000
101583816||1805434338|420_99_0122818689|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|10000|0|0|10000
```

but to get the output shown in your example (retain rows with values in the 2nd **and** 3rd columns):

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*' '($2 != "") && ($3 != "")' file
101583815|1605227222|1605227234|412_99_0122818689|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|10000|0|0|10000|MARIA
101578445|HOLA|1605434338|412_99_0123259149|2020-09-24 00:00:00.000|2020-10-09 00:00:00.000|0|8000|0|0|8000
```